# What is wrong with my code on making comments?

Tags: mysql, node.js

This is my code on making comments.
It turns out that it has a reference error. It says that comments is not defined.
What should I change?

```
<ul>
  <% for (var i=0; i<comments.length; i++){ %>
    <li><%= comments[i].comment %> /
    <%= moment(comments[i].inserted).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a') %> </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>

<form method="post" action="news/comment">
  <input type="hidden" name="articleId" value="<%= news.id %>">
  <textarea name="comment"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="댓글달기">
</form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define `comments` variable and it should be `array`

Comment: how do you define comments? and what should be array? sorry i'm new

Comment: this depends on what you are trying to do, 
what kind of template engine you use?
 seems like you are trying to display comments, 
so you must pass `comments` from the server to the template engine then you will access the comments  so it will be defined

Comment: then do i have to make comment.js file? i'm using java node.js

Comment: yes , also it depends on how you want to handle comments, you can name whatever you want.

Comment: thank you so much. do you know what to put in the comment.js file?

Comment: sorry no, this returns to you

Comment: select this answer as correct answer if you see it helpful and correct, so other people can find it easy